# How to select Cluster keys that are in the same partition key?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm creating a like oneToMany relationShip with cassandra CQL 3, 
A service may have different responses, and response belong to one service.

I would like to know if there's a function that can let me select Cluster keys that are in the same partition key?

```
CREATE TABLE reponse (
 service_id uuid,
 service_nom text static,
 service_timeout boolean static,
 reponse_id uuid,
 reponse_type boolean,
 reponse_nom text,
 reponse_valide boolean,
 reponse_message text,

 PRIMARY KEY((service_id), reponse_type, reponse_id )
);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand clearly your problem. Can you give us and example ?